# Add validator and description to file upload form

Tags: 7, forms, files, media

I want to check the min width of a picture when using the file upload form (file_entity_add_upload).

normally I would do

```
function my_module_form_file_entity_add_upload_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  // Adds a description to the upload field.
  $form['file']['#description'] = t('Min width @limit pixels', array('@limit' => 768));

  // Specific validations.
    $form['#validate'][] = 'budg_eu_project_file_entity_add_upload_validate';
}
```

but that doesn't work.

How should I declare the description and the validator?